# Is the order of Catch blocks important?

Tags: c#, exception

Just making sure I understand it well. Is the correct schema correct? Catching the most specific exceptions first to catching broader exceptions with general catch at the end of the set of catch blocks.

```
try
{
 some code
}


catch(SomeSpecificException ex)
{
}
catch(LessSpecificException ex)
{
}
catch
{
  //some general exception
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the correct order.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960259/catching-exceptions-c/3960283#3960283?

Comment: If you mean "more specific" as "is derived from the less specific exception class", then yes. However, if one does not inherit from the other, then you can put them in whatever order you want. You can argue that `FileNotFoundOnAnyServerException` is _semantically_ more specific than a `FileNotFoundException`. But if it does not inherit from `FileNotFoundException`, there is no risk of conflict, and therefore the compiler does not care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it won't let you write it in the incorrect order.

This generates an error:

```
try
{
    throw new OutOfMemoryException();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    "B".Dump();
}
catch(OutOfMemoryException ex)
{
    "A".Dump();
}
```

Comment: "A previous catch clause already catches all exceptions of this or of a super type ('System.Exception')", to be specific.

Comment: @ Martinho Fernandes I think compiler wont let me compile it.

Comment: @Loj: exactly. And it will give you the error message I mentioned.